# Is there a way to backup/restore my desktop config settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I have my Windows 10 desktop configured appearance wise just the way I like it.

- I received an update last week that completely messed up the appearance.
- It added Cortana back in, and the start menu tiles opened up on start and took over most of my desktop.
- My right click options on the task bar were extremely limited (e.g I couldn't launch task manager).

I was able to go back to my previous configuration by going to a restore point prior to the update (3/16/2016).

I'm concerned that I will get the update again, and my personalizations will go away.

What is most practical approach to ensure that my desktop customizations remain intact, or so I can easily retrieve them?

Comment: I use [WinAero](http://winaero.com/) and [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) to tailor my W10 settings. The latter can save and load settings from a file, while the former has a bookmark feature for the settings you have changed.